# Downloaded file by means of Java does not open

Tags: java

I try to open downloaded file but it's impossible. For example *.mp3 does not play *.torrent have message " is not valid bencoding".. Whats's wrong? Promt please?

```
try(FileOutputStream fwriter = new FileOutputStream(save_location);){
        URL url_path = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = url_path.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        int data;
        while((data = reader.read())!=-1)
            fwriter.write(data);
        fwriter.flush();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.

The code is taking an input stream (binary data) and wrapping it in a reader (text data) with the conversion of binary to text being performed using the platform's default character set decoder.

Then it is taking those characters, truncating them to bytes and writing them as a byte syteam.

A transformation of binary data from bytes to characters and back to bytes is typically<sup>1</sup> lossy; i.e. to damages binary data.  When you do it like this (without selecting a "safe" charset, and with a broken text to byte conversion on the back end) then damage is inevitable.

For the record, here is a sketch of the correct way to copy a binary data stream:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(save_location);
     URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
     InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE);
    int nosBytesRead;
    while ((nosBytesRead = is.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(data, 0, nosBytesRead);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Does no convert from bytes to chars to bytes
2. Does reads and writes using a buffer, not one byte (or character) at a time.
3. Does not squash exceptions.
4. Opens the input stream as resource so that there is no potential resource leak.

---

<sup>1 - But not always.  If you use Latin-1 as the character encoding, and implement the conversions correctly, they won't be lossy.  But this is beside the point really.  For a binary data you should not do an unnecessary binary -> text -> binary transformation in the first place.</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and advice.